# How I can add class to just first div above?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I can do it by different js but in this case it is not an option

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  if($('.panel-default .panel-collapse').hasClass('in')) {
    $(this).prev('.panel-heading').addClass('show-in');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">

  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse 
                               in">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">

  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse 
                               in">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">

  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: TO which div u want to add class?

Comment: @Pavlina If someone's solution solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. For more info: [how does accepting an answer work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS pseudo selector `:first-of-type` to target the first element in a series

Example:

```css
.panel-default:first-of-type {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">1</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">2</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">3</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">4</div>
<div class="panel panel-default">5</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This must because `this` variable is not there. Since this is on ready, use the following.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.panel-default .panel-collapse.in')
         .prev('.panel-heading')
         .addClass('show-in');
});
```